# adding a swf in html5

Tags: html

I am trying to add a xml flash image banner to an html document. Here is a link - http://harden6615.com/project2/site/index.html - It works fine if I add the .swf and other element to the file with index.html but when I nest the banner files inside a folder and use the path, I get no banner. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

[image: screenshot]

```
<section>
       <div id="slideshow">
        <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="500" height="312" id="slideshow" align="middle">
    <param name="movie" value="banner/slideshow.swf" />
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="banner/slideshow.swf" width="500" height="312">
            <param name="movie" value="banner/slideshow.swf" />
        <!--<![endif]-->
            <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
     <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
            </a>
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        </object>
        <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>
        </div>
</section>
```

Comment: organization...don't like bunched up files. I could just bring the 4 files into the index but is there no way of just putting them in a file name "slide" like I did?

Comment: Live demo? Also, might be best not to use Flash nowadays – something like Swiffy (http://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/) has an online converter to allow you to serve up non flash content where required.

Comment: yeah, live demo would do so we can debug it.

Comment: I will keep that in mind Rich. I am used to flash but not as much used to html so I am still learning in school. I've added the live demo but now it seems to look different which could tip there is a problem. Changed the file to banner to test. The link is in the description.

Comment: how about a screenshot of the folder tree in explorer (windows)? that way we could visualize the structure.

Comment: Screenshot up top. Lol can't believe this took so much work. I will look into the swiffy later in my sparetime.

Comment: That swiffy say it does not support actionscript and my whole banner is done in xml and actionscript only. So not sure how thats effective if I have a ton of images. Anyway, I guess Ill just add them to the root because this is taking too long and I need to finish. So up until now there is no correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is your folder structure? i suppose the index.html and the folder are siblings and the folder contains the files (the way i understood your question). then your path should not be `../slideshow.swf` but `foldername/slideshow.swf`

Comment: I have index in the root, css is in a folder called css/styles.css and the banner is in a folder called in a folder called "slide" so slide/slideshow.swf. I tried using the name but I got nothing. I'll try it again. Maybe I made a typo. I'll update the code to show it with the name.

Comment: Doesn't work. There has to be a reason why my banner is not showing? Should there be a link to something else inside my file. Maybe the xml? Doubt it but just using slide/slideshow.swf is not working.

Comment: try clearing the cache and debug with firebug (or similar tools)

Comment: well I tested it in safari, chrome and opera. so is it the cache really? wow I can't believe I have to bring this into the root and crowd my files.

Comment: browsers have a tendency to cache pages indefinitlely that's why you should clear the cache. you could _CTRL + LEFT SHIFT + R_ to reload from resource instead of from the cache. works on chrome and firefox.

Comment: since you are doing html5, try this: `<embed src="banner/slideshow.swf" />` as stated in http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_embed.asp

Comment: LOL what's funny with that is with the html5 embed banner/slideshow.swf works but also slideshow.swf works and if I remove the objects from the root folder but not in the banner folder, the banner goes away on the browser. I'm going to move on fskreuz, thanks for you help, but I'll just add this to the root and come back to this later. You can provide an answer if you ever figure it out.